# JSON POST data in Node.JS serialized as array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, post

Trying to get POST data from my front-end form. When I run a `console.log(req.body)` I get the following:

```
[ { name: 'name', value: 'kevin' }
  { name: 'email', value: '' },
  { name: 'phone', value: '' },
  { name: 'message', value: '' } ]
```

Problem: My current output on `console.log(req.body.name)` is : `Undefined`

The expected output is: `kevin`

Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to avoid? I dont understand enough about JSON and im trying to learn.

Thanks

Comment: because, `req.body` is an array, you have to loop over each element or, (bad way) 
 `req.body[0].name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to avoid?**

Try like this way using `forEach()` to get name/value because you `req.body` is an `array of object` so you've to iterate it and grab **name or value** from it like below way and avoid `undefined` output. Also If you just want any specific name/value from your `array of object` try like this without `forEach` loop like 
`req.body[0].name` or `req.body[0].value`. Hope you understand now :)

```js
const array_of_obj = [{
    name: 'name',
    value: 'kevin'
  }, {
    name: 'email',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'phone',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'message',
    value: ''
  }
];

array_of_obj.forEach((elm) => {
  console.log(`name = ${elm.name} and value = ${elm.value}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`req.body` will be an array of object. You need to iterate over it using `forEach` for conventional for loop and get the value.

If you want to get only the element from the first object then do `req.body[0].name` where `[0]` is the index

Answer (score 1):

Check this example I created. Hope this will help

```
    var json1 = {"players":[
          {"name":"Messi", "goals":8},
          {"name":"Ronaldo", "goals":22},
          {"name":"Costa", "goals":20},
          {"name":"Neymar", "goals":13},
          {"name":"Arabi", "goals":6},
          {"name":"Bale", "goals":3},
          {"name":"Toquero", "goals":0}]};
    console.log(json1.players[0]);
    for(let item of json1.players){
     console.log(item);
    }
```